# Cannot insert to MySql database

Tags: post, insert, null

I'm working with a gsm shield and try to post data to my server and then show it to website but have a problem when insert to the table. It's just Null (0). I try all the method that I found on the internet but still doesn't work. These are some code I tried

```
<?php

  $server = "localhost";
  $username = "id1342*****nhchuot";
  $password = "*******";
  $dbname = "id134****ta";

  $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $dbname);
  $Data = $_POST['data'];
  $Received = $_POST['received'];

  $query = "INSERT INTO DATA(data, received) 
  VALUES ('".$Data."','".$Received."')";
  mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
    echo "Error: " .  $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);

mysqli_close($conn);?>
```

and database just 0 and 0

[image: @@]

Comment: you are executing the insert query twice. Why?

Comment: twice? i cannot understand it clearly, can you explain?

Comment: Also, check that your post variables are not empty. do a var_dump($_POST) on this page. If you get your variable, check your database for the column types. if its varchar, int etc